# Python button bot with vscode does not work when switching to another application

Tags: python, pyautogui

I started playing a game. Constantly pressing the 'space' button made me tired. For this, I tried something on Vscode. But the code only works on Vscode. It stops when I switch to another application. When I switch to vscode it continues again.
This is the first problem I want to solve.

What I exactly want is to set the 'Space' command as a key in the game and if I press it, the program will start. (Normally there was no if line of code. I just tried that for the second problem. it didn't work)

```
import pyautogui
def taskes():
    if pyautogui.press('scrollock'):
        pyautogui.press('space') 
while True: 
    taskes()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code like this:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

# Wait for the 'a' key to be pressed
keyboard.wait('a')

def taskes():
    pyautogui.press('space')

while True:
    taskes()
```

It should wait until you press the 'a' key to start your loop now.

If you have not done it yet, you need to install the keyboard library first:

```
pip install keyboard
```